# Parsing HTTP response String / Buffer

Tags: node.js, parsing, http

I'm trying to parse an HTTP response in the form of a `String` or `Buffer` into an `Object`.

The result would be an `Object` like the native `http` module's response.

I tried to import the native HTTP parser, but the results were too raw for my use-case :

```
var HTTPParser = process.binding('http_parser').HTTPParser;

var parser = new HTTPParser(HTTPParser.RESPONSE);

parser.onHeadersComplete = function(res) {
    console.log('onHeadersComplete');
    console.log(res);
};

parser.execute(data, 0, data.length);
```

which would return something like this :

```
onHeadersComplete
{
   headers: 
   [ 'X-Powered-By',
     'Express',
     'Content-Type',
     'text/plain',
     'Content-Length',
     '2',
     'Date',
     'Sat, 19 Apr 2014 20:16:45 GMT',
     'Connection',
     'keep-alive' ],
  statusCode: 200,
  versionMajor: 1,
  versionMinor: 1,
  shouldKeepAlive: true,
  upgrade: false 
}
```

Two things are lacking for my use-case :

1. map of header names associated with header values
2. parsing the response body

   - Does anyone know how to achieve this ?

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: Why are you trying to manually parse an HTTP response?

Comment: Because I'm writing a fuzzer which uses Node.js's `net` module to send mis-constructed `HTTP` requests to test HTTP servers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to fill all the callbacks.

```
var HTTPParser = require('http-parser-js').HTTPParser;
var parser = new HTTPParser(HTTPParser.RESPONSE);
parser.onHeadersComplete = function(res) {
    console.log(res.headers);
};
parser.onBody = function(chunk, offset, length) {
    console.log("body", chunk.toString(), offset, length)
}
parser.onMessageComplete = function() {

}
parser.execute(new Buffer('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; xya\r\nContent-Length: 11\r\n\r\nhello world'))
```

Answer (score 0):

For headers transform you can use private method `http.IncomingMessage(socket)._addHeaderLines(headersArr, headersNumber)`

```
var msg=new http.IncomingMessage()

msg._addHeaderLines(['X-Powered-By',
     'Express',
     'Content-Type',
     'text/plain',
     'Content-Length',
     '2',
     'Date',
     'Sat, 19 Apr 2014 20:16:45 GMT',
     'Connection',
     'keep-alive' ], 10);
console.log(msg);
```

Result:

```
IncomingMessage {
  ...
  headers:
   { 'x-powered-by': 'Express',
     'content-type': 'text/plain',
     'content-length': '2',
     date: 'Sat, 19 Apr 2014 20:16:45 GMT',
     connection: 'keep-alive' },
  rawHeaders:
   [ 'X-Powered-By',
     'Express',
     'Content-Type',
     'text/plain',
     'Content-Length',
     '2',
     'Date',
     'Sat, 19 Apr 2014 20:16:45 GMT',
     'Connection',
     'keep-alive' ],
  ...
 }
```

Usage sample from Node sources: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_http_common.js

Answer (score -1):

I'm also trying to study node.js and I just started yesterday. Since it's a javascript thing, here's my suggested solution.

I assume the object being parsed here is 'res' argument.

```
var headers = {};
for (index = 0; index < res.headers.length; index++) {
    headers[res.headers[index].replace('-', '')] = res.headers[++index];
}

// or this
for (index = 0; index < res.headers.length; index+=2) {
    var headerName = res.headers[index].replace('-', '');
    headers[headerName] = res.headers[index + 1];
}

// Note that we removed the '-' in the name since it's an invalid character for property name.

// Access sample.
console.log(headers.ContentType);
console.log(headers['ContentType']);
```

I hope it helped you out.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not trying to remodel the Express objects. What I want to do is parse HTTP protocol "packets" from a TCP stream result buffer.